# C++ OOP design: Scope owning Widgets

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, scope, widget

I am trying to design an interface of widgets ADT in which:

1. Each Widget can have children widgets.
2. Widgets are polymorphic (derived by TextBox for instance).
3. All widgets are related to a scope, that supplies services to them (like finding another widgets by filtering, managing shared data resources).
4. The whole structure could be serialized.

I thought to force a widget to be constructed only be the scope. The widgets are owned by the Scope (even childrens), so that only ids are saved in the widgets (the actual widget could be retrieved by the related Scope).
usage:

```
Scope scope;
TextBox& txtBox1 = scope.create<TextBox>();
TextBox& txtBox2 = scope.create<TextBox>("Enter text..");
txtBox1.setText("...");
txtBox1.setParent(label); // label is a widget in this scope. if not, txtBox1 will be replaced into the label's scope.
```

Structure:

```
class Widget {
    string id;
    Scope* scope;
protected:
    Widget(Scope& _scope)
    : id(generateUniqId()), scope(&_scope) {}
public:
    ...
    virtual ~Widget() = default;
    const string& getId() const {return id;}
    friend class Scope;
};
class TextBox : public Widget {
    string text;
protected:
    TextBox(Scope& _scope) : Widget(_scope) {} 
    TextBox(Scope& _scope, string text) : Widget(_scope), text(text) {} 
public:
    virtual ~TextBox() = default;
    const string& getText() const {return text;}
    friend class Scope;
};
class Scope {
    map<string, unique_ptr<Widget>> widgets;
public:
    ...
    template <class T, class... Args>
    T& create(Args&&... args) {
        unique_ptr<T> widget(new T(*this, args...));
        string id = widget->getId();
        widgets.insert(make_pair(id, move(widget)));
        return dynamic_cast<T&>(*widgets[id]);
    }
};
```

The problems are:

1. All derived classes must hide their c'tor, and make Scope a friend class.
2. Each c'tor must get a Scope& parameter.
3. Not intuitive to use.

Is it considered as a bad design? Are there another ideas that meets my requirements?

Very thanks.
Elad